# Magento multiple VAT classes

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, vat, gift-card

I am trying to set up a Magento Shop for a German restaurant that also has some events.
We would like to sell Tickets that contain entry & food. Problem is, we have two different VAT situations here. for entry we have 19% and for food it's 7%.

So if we sell an entry&food combo for lets say 100€, we need to apply 19% on 50€ and 7% on the other 50€.

I tried that by creating 2 virtual products (entry & food) and combining them via a bundle product. That works well but Magento does not allow other product types then simple and virtual to be combined in a bundle.

I would like to use a gift-card plugin that creates it's own product type. Something like this one: http://www.magetrend.com/magento-2-gift-card

Is there

- a) A different/better approach to fix this VAT problem or
- b) A way to    bundle other product types that simple & virtual